# How to run the shopping cart example of wildfly in netbeans?

Tags: maven, netbeans, wildfly

I'm trying to run shopping cart example from here : https://github.com/sgilda/wildfly-quickstart/tree/master/shopping-cart

I was able to deploy it onto the server from Netbeans but how the hell do I actually run it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use official quick starts which come with all instructions you need.

You can find official WildFly quick starts [here](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/)

And the shopping cart [one](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/shopping-cart) 
and read README.md that explains everything.

Comment: It doesn't say how to run on netbeans, but it does say how to run on Eclipse and cli though.